# Ошибка в коде С++. В какую сторону копать?

Tags: c++, структуры, типы-данных, константа

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>


using namespace std;


typedef struct Train                                  //объявляем структуру:
{
    int size = 0;
    const int n = 5;                                //порядковый номер поезда
    char city_name[255];                                    //название города
    int numberOfTrain;                                      //номер поезда
    int departure_time;                                     //время отправления

}Train;


Train sh[10];                                              //объявляем массив структур



void FillData(int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        do {
            cout << "Введите порядковый номер поезда: " << i + 1 << endl;
            cin >> sh[i].n;
        } 
        while (!strcmp(sh[i].n, ""));
        cout << "Название города: " << endl;
        cin >> sh[i].city_name;
        do {
            cout << "Номер поезда: " << endl;
            cin >> sh[i].numberOfTrain;
        } while (!strcmp(sh[i].numberOfTrain, ""));
        cout << "Время отправления: " << endl;
        cin >> sh[i].departure_time;
}



int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

    cout << "Расписание поездов" << endl;
    cout << "Версия 1.0" << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Нажмите Enter для продолжения" << endl;
    getchar();                                              //заглушка


    FillData(5);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: В сторону дебагера

Answer (score 2):

Для начала - копать [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

А потом подумать - если переменная объявлена как константа, то как вы собираетесь вносить в нее новое значение?

```
cin >> sh[i].n;
```

Ведь `n` в структуре `Train` объявлена как `const int`.

А ведь вы еще и пытаетесь сравнивать это *целое число* со строкой...

```
strcmp(sh[i].n, "")
```

Еще скобки у вас расставлены так, что только цикл `do..while` является телом цикла `for`, так что все последующие строки не понимают, что такое переменная `i`.

Для начала, думаю, хватит?

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, Harry! Но почему-то цикл do..while не видит массив sh[]?

Comment: И снова для начала: Вы опять сравниваете целое со строкой while (!strcmp(sh[i].numberOfTrain, "").

Comment: Что значит "*не видит*"? Вы конкретнее пишите - хочу то-то, вывод компилятора такой-то...

Comment: Интересно, кто минус поставил - сообщите хоть, в чем я неправ :)